# Perl add delimiter and remove last one

Tags: perl

I have file with few lines, I want combine all lines with delimiter and remove the last one.

Its not working with perl. but working with sed. can you help to make this work with perl?

```
 cat a
a
b
c
d

 cat a |perl -lane 'printf("%s|",$_)' |perl -lane 's/|$//;print'
a|b|c|d|

 cat a |perl -lane 'printf("%s|",$_)' |sed 's/|$//'
a|b|c|d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why add then remove?

```
perl -pe'chomp; $_="|$_" if $. > 1; END { print "\n"; }'
```

---

By the way,

```
cat file | perl -e'...'   # Useless use of cat
```

can be written as

```
perl -e'...' <file
```

And since all solutions provided read from ARGV, you can even drop the redirection and pass the file name as an argument.

```
perl -e'...' file
```

---

For fun, golfing:

```
perl -pE'chomp;$.>1&&s/^/|/;END{say""}'  # Based on mine
perl -nlE'push@L,$_}{$"="|";say"@L"'     # Based on JRF's
perl -E'chomp(@L=<>);say join"|",@L'
perl -0777pe's/\n(?!\z)/|/g'
```

Only the first wastes no memory. The last one is probably the fastest.

Comment: One more to abuse `-l`: `perl -l174 -nE'eof()?say:print'`

Comment: @ikegam thanks multiple oneliner, this helps me to learn more tricks.

Answer (score 4):

[join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) makes this trivial.  You could do:

```
cat a | perl -lne'push @lines,$_;END{print join "|", @lines}'
```

...but then you get the useless `cat` award, so reduce that to:

```
perl -lne'push @lines,$_;END{print join "|", @lines}' a

a|b|c|d
```

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for dropping the useless `chomp` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping it,

```
cat a |perl -lane 'printf("%s|",$_)' |perl -lane 's/\|$//;print'
```

Perl sees `|` as an `or` in a search-and-replace.

Comment: As a note, the other solutions make the original statement much more readable.